# What impact have on performance of page loading when we use multiple Lightning:RecordForm in a single component

Tags: lightning, lightning-record-form, aura-if

We are using multiple `lightning:recordForm` in different `aura:if`  for the different condition in a single custom Lightning Component for showing different 
 field. Is it the best practice to use multiple `lightning:recordForm` at a time?

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.check=='a'}">
    <lightning:recordForm 
        recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
        objectApiName="My_Contact__c"
        layoutType="Full" 
        mode="view" />
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.check=='b'}">
    <lightning:recordForm 
        recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
        objectApiName="My_Contact__c"
        layoutType="Full" 
        mode="view" />
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.check=='c'}">
    <lightning:recordForm 
        recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
        objectApiName="My_Contact__c"
        layoutType="Full" 
        mode="view" />
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Why not use if clause on fields? instead of on record form? seems like an overkill

Comment: Thanks, @PranayJaiswal Yes, you are right. I will try in that way too. But my curiosity was to know the performance effect and best practice to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aura:if` doesn't even *create* the components contained within unless `isTrue` is true. As such, you're really only creating one `lightning:recordForm` at a time as far as performance is concerned. You can expect nominal performance from this design, assuming there's not too many `aura:if` elements (they're pretty fast, but too many can be a performance concern), but you'd need a few hundred to feel any real performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this valuable information, @sfdcfox. This information is not available anywhere as I tried to find it a lot.

Comment: @sanketkumar it's [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_if.htm): "aura:if instantiates the components in either its body or the else attribute, but not both. ... If the state of isTrue changes, aura:if has to first instantiate the components for the other state and then render them. We recommend using aura:if instead of aura:renderIf to improve performance."